# Losing all data on VF page after pressing F5 button

Tags: visualforce

I have a strange situation. I have created a VF page which has 2 output panels. The 1st panel is showing list of all search result in a `pageblock` table. Clicking any result from that table will show the details of that particular record in the 2nd output panel.

Whenever a user by mistake clicks the F5 button the page gets refreshed, is loaded with the 1st panel and the user loses the data of 2 panel. But in real time user should be on that particular state after refresh the page.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are encountering desired and intended behavior. Hitting F5 causes the page to be refreshed, thus reloading it fresh; your page has no way of knowing what was previously entered. This is different from a postback where viewstate will maintain the contents non-transient input fields.

**Edit**

Possible workarounds for this behavior:

1. When a user selects a record from the first table, cause a postback that provides that record Id in the URL. Your controller could then use that as a parameter to populate the second table by default.
2. Use JavaScript to append the record Id to the query string.
3. Store the value of the last selected record Id in a cookie. You can do this with JavaScript or server-side, but I would recommend using JavaScript to update the cookie when the record is selected. There is a [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) that will simplify this process.

Comment: Thanks!!! you are correct..that is the main problem,While hitting F5 page is again reloaded.So is there any solution for this problem.

Comment: I have added some ideas for workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for help...But I am not able to store the value of last selected recordid in cookie.Can you help me in this .It would be really helpful.

Comment: I've added a link to the jQuery cookie plugin. For further details I would suggest searching for a jQuery cookie tutorial or searching StackOverflow as it is no longer Salesforce specific.

Answer (score 1):

While kind of evil, you could also do an JavaScript catch on the onclose event.  Here's a jQuery example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333665/javascript-to-get-an-alert-when-closing-the-browser-window