# Visualforce page action method (< apex:page action="{!IsValidUser} >) does not get invoked when VF page used in force.com site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I am seeing some strange issue in force.com site page.

1. I have created 2 visualforce pages.
2. After saving some information on first page I am redirecting the user to second page using action method.
3. On second page, I have used a action method which will check whether the user should see second page or not. 
   < apex:page action="{!IsValidUser}   >

public PageReference IsValidUser(){

//Logic to redirect the user

}

4. When I access the second page like salesforce.com/apex/secondPage then action method {!IsValidUser} gets invoked every time when I refresh the page from the org.
5. However, when I use the same page in force.com site like
   developer-edition.na7.force.com/secondpage then action method {!IsValidUser}  DOES NOT get invoked every time when I refresh the page from url.
6. It gets invoked when I redirect the page from firstPage to secongPage using action method.

Does anyone has any idea about this issue?

---

@ Mark Pond,

Thank you for your response. Please find below my action method:

public PageReference IsValidUser(){
 String uid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('uid');

```
User_Registration__c userRegToUpdate;
    try{
                  User_Registration__c uReg = [Select id,IsRedirectedFromFirstPage__c from User_Registration__c where UID__c =:uid];
                  if(uReg.IsRedirectedFromFirstPage__c == true){
                  userRegToUpdate = new User_Registration__c(id=uReg.id);
                  userRegToUpdate.IsRedirectedFromFirstPage__c = false;
                  update userRegToUpdate;
                 }
                  else{
                      //Redirect user to login page if IsRedirectedFromFirstPage__c is false
                      PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/indexApex');
                      pageRef.setRedirect(true);
                      return pageRef;
                  }

    }catch(Exception e){
    System.debug('***Exception***'+e);
    }

return null;
}
```

Visualforce page which I am using for second page is like below:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Account" extensions="loginPageController" action="{!IsValidUser}" >   </apex:page>
```

Mark, while doing some research on this issue, I found that I am facing this issue in Mozilla browser, when I just paste my site url in address bar and hit enter it does not execute action method, however, when I hit f5 to refresh the page, action method does execute. Is it related to below issue?

[Losing all data on VF page after pressing F5 button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9637/losing-all-data-on-vf-page-after-pressing-f5-button)

Thanks,
Jagmohan

Comment: Can you add the controller code and the VF markup of these two pages to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @LaceySnr I have updated my question, please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Did you get any solution to your problem ? I am also facing a similar issue.

Comment: Is `cache=false` on page _and_ composition template?